# Update download progress from Service to activity

Tags: android, android-service

I'm downloading data in Android app. The flow is- Activity starts a service which downloads multiple files using [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). Now I want to show the progress in Activity UI. How can I send progress from service to activity?

My approach is- broadcast a message when a file is downloaded by service. In Activity, use broadcast receiver to receive progress. Is this approach good enough? If not what is the best way to do?

Comment: are you downloading in the background service?? why not to use `Asynctask` ??

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Yes a background service. The downloading task takes time. What I read from docs is `AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just create a static method in the activity...

**Like this**

```
public static void updateUI(String value) {
  //your coding logic
}
```

Then call this from your service

**Like This**

```
(Your activity name).updateUI(value);
```

Comment: is this way "secure"?

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with your activity you can use `LocalBroadCastManager`.

Send update from service:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receive update in activity:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
                receiver, intentFilter);
```

Check document https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html#ReportStatus